# Loading Fivestar with AJAX

Tags: 7, ajax, rating

I need a way to load Fivestar via AJAX for a onepage.

Currently I load every section async but need to init the votes afterwards. Otherwise I only see the dropdown menu and the rate button. When I try to select something in the dropdown menu it'll get reset.

Does anyone know a solution? Thanks

Comment: Okay, I found out what to add and edit... now the form gets converted into divs and links, but clicking won't have any affect. But ajax-files are loaded (of system and fivestar)